# How to share dbcontext to entire razor web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor

I read alot thread said in aspnet to share connection database to controller and page is through dependency injection. so i follow this tutorial [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0). but after implement this. dotnet-ef migrations not working. before its work. migrations works when i remove dbcontext service. and put configuration in applicationcontext class. what is cause this?

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationContext'. For the
> different patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Program.cs

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => 
    options.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

ApplicationContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options) {}
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core app will create and manage an HttpRequest scope by default through the defined middlewares.

What you want and need is to create the db context right at the beginning so it will resolve the dbContext for the dependency injection.

You can get this by creating a scope when executing program.cs and ensure the db is created (you may want to seed it by overriding `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`).

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<YoureContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectioning"))
});


var app = builder.Build();
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YoureContext>();
    //context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); //For deleting and Re-Seedng the Database
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```